# Select only certain fields from Entity isn't working Google Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

This code works:

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('contact').select('email');
```

This code does not:

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('contact').select(['email', 'isblacklisted', 'isspam', 'isunsubscribed']);
```

The output is :

```
Error: function crashed.Details:
First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

Example in documentation: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-projection-query-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projection queries require all properties specified in the projection to be included in a Cloud Datastore index.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#indexes_for_projections